# Is it possible to use Docker.DotNet to start a container programmatically on Azure Pipelines?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, microservices, azure-pipelines

I have a microservices application and I wan't to start the whole stack to run integration tests. The idea is to be able to run the tests from Test Explorer within Visual Studio. So I don't want to create a shell script to be able to accomplish this.

The idea is to start all external microservice dependencies in containers and then run a TestServer of the system under test to receive the test requests so that the system can call other microservices.

I found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet) library and liked the idea of start containers programmatically to achieve the afore mentioned.

What I don't know, is if this would work running on an Azure Pipeline. What would be the correct docker engine address on Azure to initialize Docker.DotNet?

```
// Default Docker Engine on Windows
using Docker.DotNet;
DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration(
    new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine"))
     .CreateClient();
// Default Docker Engine on Linux
using Docker.DotNet;
DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration(
    new Uri("unix:///var/run/docker.sock"))
     .CreateClient();
```

Comment: Have you succeeded to do that in local environment? You can try running that in [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) with local environments before migrating it into microsoft-hosted agent.

Comment: It's working on my dev machine. Reading Ms-Hosted Agent documentation, it seems it's possible to start containers as Docker is pre-installed from the Windows image. But I don't know what is the correct named pipe address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little research and found that both Windows and Linux images for Ms-hosted agents have Docker and Docker-Compose pre-installed, so it is possible to start containers using these agents.

My problem was that I didn't realize that the Ops team configured a Linux agent. I was trying to execute using a Windows named pipe and not a Unix socket.

I changed the Docker Engine API address accordingly and it worked.

Here is my code in case someone is interested in creating Integration Tests that start containers for microservices dependencies:

```
using Docker.DotNet;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Relationship.Promotion.Applier.IntegrationTest.Helpers
{
    public class DockerClientFactory
    {
        private static readonly Uri defaultWindowsDockerEngineUri = new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine");
        private static readonly Uri defaultLinuxDockerEngineUri = new Uri("unix:///var/run/docker.sock");

        public static DockerClient CreateInstance()
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
                return new DockerClientConfiguration(defaultWindowsDockerEngineUri).CreateClient();
            else
                return new DockerClientConfiguration(defaultLinuxDockerEngineUri).CreateClient();
        }
    }
}

namespace Relationship.Promotion.Applier.IntegrationTest
{
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        private readonly DockerClient dockerClient;
        private readonly PromotionContainer promotionContainer;
        private readonly StoreContainer storeContainer;
        private readonly ConversionContainer conversionContainer;

        public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
        {
            try
            {
                // Alternative to Docker.DotNet
                // https://github.com/Deffiss/testenvironment-docker
                dockerClient = DockerClientFactory.CreateInstance();

                DockerContainerBase.CleanupOrphanedContainers(dockerClient).Wait(300.Seconds());

                if (!dockerClient.Networks.ListNetworksAsync().Result.Select(n => n.Name).Contains("boti-network"))
                {
                    var result = dockerClient.Networks.CreateNetworkAsync(new Docker.DotNet.Models.NetworksCreateParameters()
                    {
                        Name = "boti-network",
                        Driver = "bridge"
                    }).Result;
                }

                promotionContainer = new PromotionContainer(imageName: "promotion-engine-promotion-api");
                promotionContainer.Start(dockerClient).Wait(300.Seconds());

                conversionContainer = new ConversionContainer(imageName: "promotion-engine-conversion-api");
                conversionContainer.Start(dockerClient).Wait(300.Seconds());

                storeContainer = new StoreContainer("promotion-engine-store-api");
                storeContainer.Start(dockerClient).Wait(300.Seconds());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                throw;
            }
        }

        protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
        {
            return base.CreateWebHostBuilder().UseEnvironment("Docker");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool itIsSafeToAlsoFreeManagedObjects)
        {
            if (!itIsSafeToAlsoFreeManagedObjects) return;

            promotionContainer.Remove(dockerClient).Wait(300.Seconds());
            conversionContainer.Remove(dockerClient).Wait(300.Seconds());
            storeContainer.Remove(dockerClient).Wait(300.Seconds());

            dockerClient.Dispose();

            base.Dispose(itIsSafeToAlsoFreeManagedObjects);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't know, is if this would work running on an Azure Pipeline.
> What would be the correct docker engine address on Azure to initialize
> Docker.DotNet?

You can add [Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline which runs in hosted windows agent, with content like this:

```
[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\") | Select-String "docker"
```

Here's the result if I use hosted windows2019 agent:

[image]

So I think the address is `\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine` (not sure if it needs some changes like slash and backslash when using in your code).